# What is an idiomatic way to pass by interface without being really gross and typographically heavyweight?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to understand the *right* way to handle a specific abstraction problem. Let's use my current struggles with `thread_rng` as a proxy for the larger problem.

I want to pass around a single instance of a random number generator to various functions. I don't want them to know about the implementation (or size!) of the struct, just use its defined interface. Today it's `thread_rng()`, but maybe tomorrow it'll need to be some other thing, and I don't want to rewrite the code that uses it.

The obvious thing to do is to use the `rand::Rng` trait, but passing it around seems really gross and (at least typographically) heavyweight. If I understand correctly, anything I pass my trait-implementing struct to will need to use generics to monomorphize, correct? Is this just how people do it, or is there another way?

Code example:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::prelude::*;

mod sim {
    use rand::Rng;

    pub fn generate_numbers<TRng : Rng>(r: &mut TRng) -> i32 {
        r.gen_range(42, 45)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    let result = sim::generate_numbers(&mut rng);

    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

This looks fine in such a constrained example, but in my codebase I might be passing the RNG down through several layers of function calls across modules before it finally arrives at the leaf function that actually acts on it. Everything between gets this massive dusting of generics. I can only imagine how bad it will look when there are more than a few things I want to abstract like this.

What's the must Rust way to do this? Maybe define a struct to hold this sort of context, and put the trait in a box? I don't know how to do that (can't box a trait like `Rng`) without making the containing struct itself generic -- which, again, is going to litter generics everywhere I have to pass this containing struct.

Maybe I'm just whining too much about generics because they remind me of C++ templates.

Comment: I do want to comment that while Sebastian's solution works great in this specific case, you're going to have a very hard time avoiding generics as a general rule. They are extremely common practice in idiomatic Rust code.

Comment: Yeah, totally fair. I'm not opposed in theory. It's more that it started to feel like a code smell. (I'm probably still not thinking about the problem properly, although I suppose pseudo-global/shared state like a PRNG is always a sticking point for languages like this.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the new impl trait short syntax for this:

```
mod sim {
    use rand::Rng;

    pub fn generate_numbers(r: &mut impl Rng) -> i32 {
        r.gen_range(42, 45)
    }
}
```

This doens't really change the meaning of the code, but it makes it less heavyweight.

Comment: Oh, interesting. That looks like it addresses exactly my concerns (and then some). Many thanks!

For anyone who comes along later, it looks like this is currently documented [here](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/2018/transitioning/traits/impl-trait.html).